How can I get CollectionView.SelectedItems from the ViewModel
I want to get the selected items from CollectionView in the view model.
I have tried binding the SelectedItems to a property of type ObservableCollection in the view model and I set the Mode to TwoWay, but it gave me binding failure and the error message was 'cannot implicitly convert type ObservableCollection to IList' so I changed the property to IList still getting 'cannot implicitly convert type IList to IList' so I made a converter:
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Converters;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Portal.ValueConverters
{
    internal class UserObservableCollectionToIListOfObjects : BaseConverter<ObservableCollection<User>, IList<object>>
    {
        public override IList<object> DefaultConvertReturnValue { get => []; set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public override ObservableCollection<User> DefaultConvertBackReturnValue { get => []; set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override ObservableCollection<User> ConvertBackTo(IList<object> value, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ObservableCollection<User> users = value as ObservableCollection<User>;
            return users;
        }

        public override IList<object> ConvertFrom(ObservableCollection<User> value, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            IList<object> objects = value as IList<object>;
            return objects;
        }
    }
}

but when I select any item the count of the property in the view model is still 0.
the CollectionView looks like this:
<CollectionView SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedMembers,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource Key=UserObservableCollectionToIListOfObjectsConverter}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}" SelectionMode="Multiple" BackgroundColor="#222">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:User">
            <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="20">
                <ImageButton Source="{Binding ImageSource}" CornerRadius="25" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Title" Margin="5" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

I have set the BindingContext in the code-behind page constructor.
and the view model look like this:
    public partial class SelectGroupMembersViewModel:ObservableObject
    {
        private readonly IUserFriendshipService _userFriendshipService;

        public Command GetUserFriendsCommand { get; }
        public Command GetSelectedMembersCommand { get; }
        public ObservableCollection<User> SelectedMembers { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<User> Friends { get; }
        public SelectGroupMembersViewModel(IUserFriendshipService userFriendshipService)
        {
            _userFriendshipService = userFriendshipService;

            GetUserFriendsCommand = new(async () => await GetUserFriendsAsync());
            GetSelectedMembersCommand = new(async () => await GetSelectedMembersAsync());

            Friends = [];
            SelectedMembers = [];
        }
        public async Task GetUserFriendsAsync()
        {
            IList<User> userFriends = await _userFriendshipService.GetCurrentUserFriendsAsync();

            Friends.Clear();
            foreach (User friend in userFriends)
                Friends.Add(friend);
        }
}


and the 'GetUserFriendsCommand' is run in the ContentPage's Loaded event by an EventToCommandBehavior.
so is there any solution or workaround for this

try public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedMembers { get; set; } instead.  A Converter is not neccesary

Actually this worked the SelectedMembers property gets the value of CollectionView.SelectedItems, but now I get this binding failure error : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SelectionList' cannot be converted to type System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection1[System.Object]'
`

Try using List instead of ObservableCollection

What .net version and platform you are targeting on? No binding issue based on your code.

@LiqunShen-MSFT I am using .NET 8 on windows

Have you tried Jason's suggestion? And no need to use the Converter. It works using .NET8 on windows.

This may not be the most efficient or smartest solution, but have you considered adding a boolean IsSelected property to the User class and updating that boolean when an item is selected?
Then, when you want to get all selected members, you can filter the Friends collection where IsSelected is true.
public class User
{
    // Existing properties
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

// Update the selection logic in the CollectionView's item tapped event
private void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedUser = e.Item as User;
    if (selectedUser != null)
    {
        selectedUser.IsSelected = !selectedUser.IsSelected;
    }
}

// In ViewModel, get selected members like this
public ObservableCollection<User> GetSelectedMembers()
{
    return new ObservableCollection<User>(Friends.Where(user => user.IsSelected));
}


but, in my case the User class is shared with the backend and it used as a database model

Also this cannot be used from the view model

You can create a UserViewModel class, and add the property. You can then map properties you would like to map from User -> UserViewModel using AutoMapper, and use the list of type UserViewModel instead of User. But I appreciate this is probably not how you do not want to implement it.

This would work too but, after I removed the converter, the binding works properly.
